# Click on option event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how do I handle events for option elements?

```
<select>
      <option value='option1'>Gateway 1</option>
      <option value='option2'>Gateway 2</option>
      <option value='option3'>Gateway 3</option>
 </select>
```

When an option element is clicked I want to display a little description for the element. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: If anyone came here for the javascript solution (not jQuery), just add an event listener for the `change` event.

Comment: For future reference, the 1st solution given in @niksvp's answer is actually the correct answer to this question. The jQuery answer given is specific to jQuery, whereas this question does not specify its use.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're going to want to use jQuery's [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/). I am displaying the text of your option as an alert, but you can display whatever you want based on your needs. (You can also, obviously, put it inside another part of the page...it doesn't need to be an alert.)

```
$('#myOptions').change(function() {
    var val = $("#myOptions option:selected").text();
    alert(val);
});
```

Also, note, that I added an ID to your `select` tag so that you can more easily handle events to it (I called it myOptions).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/S9WQv/

Answer (score 23):

As specified by *JasCav* using jQuery you can accomplish the same in javascript using

```
 <select onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);">
      <option value='option1'>Gateway 1</option>
      <option value='option2'>Gateway 2</option>
      <option value='option3'>Gateway 3</option>
 </select>
```

Alternatively, onclick event of option, but note that it is not compatible on all browsers.

```
<select>
      <option value='option1' onclick="alert(this.value);" >Gateway 1</option>
      <option value='option2'>Gateway 2</option>
      <option value='option3'>Gateway 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How is this a good solution? You can pick options with the keyboard, they will not fire anything click related.

Comment: @StevenLu - Good note, in that case you can also bind `keypress` event. But here OP is facing difficulty for `click` event, which reflects in the answer.

Comment: I suppose, but this is a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and using click is somewhere on the spectrum between marginally wrong and totally wrong. My hunch is that using both click and keyboard handlers still won't allow the feature to work on any mobile platform.

Answer (score 2):

You can write it as below mention using javascript.

```js
document.getElementById("select").addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.value)
});
```

```html
<select id="select">
      <option value='option1'>Gateway 1</option>
      <option value='option2'>Gateway 2</option>
      <option value='option3'>Gateway 3</option>
 </select>
```