# Javascript run function on <option> click

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to execute a javascript function when the user clicks on a certain `<option>` within a `<select>` drop down menu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click on option event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670405/click-on-option-event)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<select>` elements support the `onchange` event.

http://w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Answer (score 2):

You HTML would look like this:

```
<select onchange="functionName(this.value)">
    <option value="1"> 1 </option>
    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
</select>​
```

In your JavaScript, you would have a function ( ex: `functionName()` )
and you would use that function to test for each case.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
elem.onclick = function ( e ) {
    if ( e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'option' ) {
        // an <option> element was clicked
        // do your thing
    }
};
```

where `elem` is your SELECT element.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vBB7a/

Comment: @Dwellee Looks like a Chrome bug. I’ll report it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `change` event to check which option the user clicked on and then execute your desired code.

In Jquery:

```
$('#yourSelect').change(function(){
    var item = $(this).val();

    if (item === "Specified Choice")
    {
        //do your stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: seems like when someone does not specifically ask for a JQuery answer that it is kinder to answer in general javascript. Course I only say that cause I'm not what you'd call a jquery kind of guy.

Comment: I do realize that, and I used to be a non-Jquery guy as well. But its been a while since I've been using Jquery, and quite honestly, I wouldn't know how to do this in vanilla JS anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook the `onchange` event of the `<select>` element, and check the value. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `<option>` you could use the `onclick` event to specify a javascript function to be executed.

E.g.

```
<option onclick="yourFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery in your Project..

HTML Code:

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">StactOverFlow</option>
    <option value="2">SuperUser</option>
    <option value="3">Another 1</option>
    <option value="4">Another 2</option>
    <option value="5">Another 3</option>
</select>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$("#myselect").bind('change', function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "1":
            click_action_1();
            break;

        case "2":
            click_action_2();
            break;

        case "3":
            click_action_3();
            break;
    }
});

function click_action_1(){
    alert('Hi 1');
}         

function click_action_2(){
    alert('Hi 2');
}      

function click_action_3(){
    alert('Hi 3');
}
​
```

You can even execute a new javascript function with a `<option>`
Watch in Action: http://jsfiddle.net/extremerose71/PnfCk/8/

Enjoy!...