# Simulate onClick with Enter on form select option

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that passes values to a function.

```
<TR><TD>Select</TD><TD><select name=k_id>
<OPTION  value=1 onClick="myfun('10','0.1','1')">Option 1</OPTION>
<OPTION  value=2 onClick="myfun('20','0.2','2')">Option 2</OPTION>
<OPTION  value=3 onClick="myfun('30','0.3','3')">Option 3</OPTION>
<OPTION  value=4 onClick="myfun('40','0.4','4')">Option 4</OPTION>
</select>
```

```
function myfun(id,h,k,g)
    {
    var h_id=document.getElementById('h_id');
    h_id.value=id;
    var hind=document.getElementById('hind');
    hind.value=h;
    var koe=document.getElementById('koe');
    koe.value=k;
    }
```

But it doesn't work if the user selects an option using arrow keys and Enter.

How can I pass appropriate values to myfun() with pressing Enter?

I have tried:

```
<OPTION  value=1 onClick="myfun('10','0.1','1')" onkeypress="if(event.key == 'Enter') {myfun('10','0.1','1')}">Option 1</OPTION>

<OPTION  value=1 onClick="myfun('10','0.1','1')" onkeyup = "if(event.keyCode == 13){myfun('10','0.1','1')}">Option 1</OPTION>

<OPTION  value=1 onClick="myfun('10','0.1','1')" onkeydown = "if(event.keyCode == 13){myfun('10','0.1','1')}">Option 1</OPTION>
```

I have tried adding onchange to select element in the past but that had other issues. And would require rewriting the code that populates options list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the select.onchange event instead, like this:

```js
function myfun(id,h,k){
  console.log(id,h,k)
}
```

```html
<TR><TD>Select</TD><TD><select name=k_id onchange="myfun(...JSON.parse(this.value))">
<OPTION  value='["10","0.1","1"]'>Option 1</OPTION>
<OPTION  value='["20","0.2","2"]'>Option 2</OPTION>
<OPTION  value='["30","0.3","3"]'>Option 3</OPTION>
<OPTION  value='["40","0.4","4"]'>Option 4</OPTION>
</select>
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10003222/5898421) attempted to listen for clicks, and it seems like it worked at the time. But it doesn't work in the current version of Chrome.

Comment: Thank you! It works, and I like that it's short!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `onChange` call will result in a duplicate code, and more unreable thinks.

Consider placing your data in `data-` sets, so you can use a `onChange` event on the `select`. This event will trigger when your press **and** when you use your keyboard. So no need to duplicate code.

Then use `dataset` to get your data back from the new value:

```js
function myfun(event) {
    const e = event.target;
    const { id, h, k } = e.options[e.selectedIndex].dataset;
    
    console.log('Change: ', id, h, k);
}
```

```html
<TR><TD>Select</TD><TD>
<select name="k_id" onChange='myfun(event)'>
    <OPTION  value=1 data-id='10' data-h='0.1' data-k='1'>Option 1</OPTION>
    <OPTION  value=2 data-id='20' data-h='0.2' data-k='2'>Option 2</OPTION>
    <OPTION  value=3 data-id='30' data-h='0.3' data-k='3'>Option 3</OPTION>
    <OPTION  value=4 data-id='40' data-h='0.4' data-k='4'>Option 4</OPTION>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! But I chose Andrew Parks's answer because the code is shorter.

Comment: Ah oke, keep in mind that shorter doesn't mean better. I;d vote against his solution since if you are dealing with values contains eg `[` you need to start escaping etc.