# HTML select, jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, client-side

Need to get the particular option from an array of select(HTML element) using jquery.

I have an array of select element. I want to remove all the options with value = cname_0 from all the select elements available in an array, right now they are 7.

```
<select name="1" id="billData_1" onchange="validateSelectedOptions(this.id);" class="form-control deleteSelectedOption" title="Select column names" style="border: 1px solid red;">
<option value="-1">Select</option>
<option value="cname_1">Customer Name</option>
<option value="caddress_1">Address</option>
<option value="meternum_1">Meter Number</option>
<option value="reading_1">Reading</option>
<option value="readtime_1">Read Out Time</option>
</select>
<select name="2" id="billData_2" onchange="validateSelectedOptions(this.id);" class="form-control deleteSelectedOption" title="Select column names" style="border: 1px solid red;">
<option value="-1">Select</option>
<option value="cname_1">Customer Name</option>
<option value="caddress_1">Address</option>
<option value="meternum_1">Meter Number</option>
<option value="reading_1">Reading</option>
<option value="readtime_1">Read Out Time</option>
</select>
.....
...
..
<select name="7" id="billData_7" onchange="validateSelectedOptions(this.id);" class="form-control deleteSelectedOption" title="Select column names" style="border: 1px solid red;">
<option value="-1">Select</option>
<option value="cname_1">Customer Name</option>
<option value="caddress_1">Address</option>
<option value="meternum_1">Meter Number</option>
<option value="reading_1">Reading</option>
<option value="readtime_1">Read Out Time</option>
</select>

$(".deleteSelectedOption[1] option[value= 'cname_1']")
```

This is giving me empty result on console. Please help.

Comment: can you show us your HTML code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click on option event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670405/click-on-option-event)

Comment: Just added html code.

Comment: Not a duplicate. I have an array of select element. Need to do it using a class based selector. And remove all the options with value = cname_0 from all the select elements available in an array.

Comment: You do not have any option with value='cname_0' in your code. Thus empty result.

Comment: Sorry, but its not even working with cname_1

Comment: I don't think the `[1]` at the end of `.deleteSelectedOption[1]` is valid...

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks man!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#billData_1 option[value='cname_1']").remove();
```