# NodeJS, Jade Application Not Running OnClick Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

Im currently working on a Jade/NodeJS application that does not respond to an onClick function for a select option control. You can see the index.jade in the following:

```
extends layout

block content
  .jumbotron 
    h1 JSON Attribute Changer              
  .row    
    .col-md-4
      h2 Select the document
      p Use this control to select which form you want to update:     
      select.Documents.btn.btn-default        
          a.dropdown-toggle(data-toggle="dropdown")
            | Documents
            span.caret
          ul.dropdown-menu(name="documentSelector")
            each document in documents             
              option(type="option", onClick='getAttributes()') #{document._id}
```

The getAttributes() function is defined in the layout.jade file:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    title #{title} - Utilities
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(src='/javascripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js')

    script.
      function getAttributes() {
        console.log('something')
      }

  body
    etc, etc, etc.
```

The select option controls are dynamically created from entries in a Mongo db (which works fine). How can I attach the onclick function to each select option control that is created. Also, as a bonus, how could I go about using the value of the select option thats selected to retrieve its full json document from Mongo for field population?

Any and all help is awesome!

EDIT:

I just changed the Javascript code in layout.jade to reflect the following:

```
script.
      $('#DocumentOptions').change(function() {
        var val = $("#DocumentOptions option:selected").text();
        alert(val);
      });
```

I also added an ID to the select control as follows:

```
  select.Documents.btn.btn-default#DocumentOptions        
      a.dropdown-toggle(data-toggle="dropdown")
        | Documents
        span.caret
      ul.dropdown-menu(name="documentSelector")
        each document in documents             
          option #{document._id}
```

I am still not getting a response. I do not have any browser plugins running that block JS. Also, I have checked the browser console and Node console to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click on option event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670405/click-on-option-event)

Comment: I just tried the method used in the link but it didnt work. Here is my select control code:

      select.Documents.btn.btn-default#DocumentOptions        
          a.dropdown-toggle(data-toggle="dropdown")
            | Documents
            span.caret
          ul.dropdown-menu(name="documentSelector")
            each document in documents             
              option #{document._id}  

Here is the new javascript:

$('#DocumentOptions').change(function() {
        var val = $("#DocumentOptions option:selected").text();
        alert(val);
      });