# Get Id from clickable list

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a list in HTML where each item in the list can be clicked.But I need to know the ID of the item that was clicked.

I have been trying to have a div surround the list item and have an onClick and a ID tag associated. Then get the ID tag from the synthetic event.

But my list items are complex so they have sub DOM elements. Meaning if I click the `<p>` it will not return the ID associated with the div tag.

I'm not sure what the best would be to do this? strong text

Comment: Please share the code and give details

Comment: share you `HTML` at least !

Comment: use jQuery and in onclick function you can get clicked element reference by `$(this)`.

Comment: if you put some code it will help us to know how exactly is your issue

Comment: register an onclick eventhandler on some child element of your list item, in the eventhandler you have a handle on the dom element that fired the onclick event and with that you can query for it's parent list item element and get it's id...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - onClick to get the ID of the clicked button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button)

Comment: how about this [Click on option event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670405/click-on-option-event) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some solutions you can reference:

1. If using `jQuery`, try this api: `ele.closest("div")` to get the outer div tag
2. Study the javascript event popup and catch, after that you will get the answer

Answer (score 0):

This question got very good answer here: [JavaScript - onClick to get the ID of the clicked button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button)

Orginally it demonstrates button click but you can use it for your li element (or any element) that you wish.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let li = $("li");
li.on("click", getId);

function getId(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   let id = $(this).attr("id");
   console.log(id + " was clicked!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="element_1">1. Click me</li>
    <li id="element_2">2. Click me
        <ul>
            <li id="element_2.1">2.1. Click me</li>
            <li id="element_2.2">2.2. Click me</li>
            <li id="element_2.3">2.3. Click me</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="element_3">3. Click me</li>
    <li id="element_4">4. Click me</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps and if i understood you question correctly
in your HTML you can try this

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="1" class="test">Coffee</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="2" class="test">Tea</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="3" class="test">Milk</a></li>
</ul>
```

and in jquery try this

```
 $(document).on("click", ".test", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
        });
```